# How do you make a cube with another cube inside it?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, soft-body

I am making something similar to a slime in blender, with softbody. [image: picture]
I don't really know how to put a cube in it, with a darker color.

Comment: Do you mean you want a smaller cube to be able to "hop around " inside a larger cube?

Comment: no, like a cube that is stationary inside the other cube

Comment: Ok. And do you need them to be 2 separate cubes, or is "faking it" with a material acceptable (using only one cube)?

Comment: it is fine as long as it looks like a slime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting one cube inside the other, and use a Material like this on your outer cube:

[image: Cube]

Transparency can be a bit of a pain in eevee sometimes, so I opted for this form of shader graph to give you more control. You can change both the BaseColor as well as the Glossy tint separately (to get that slimy look), as well as change the IOR of the Fresnel if you need the slime to seem thicker/thinner. Also because of the way EEVEE handles transparency, the inner cube cannot be transparent as well (unless you are using a single material - the graph for which is substantially more complicated). Because of this, it doesn't matter quite as much what material you give it (I used a copy of the same one for time savings sake - I just disconnected the Transparent and associated Mix Shader).

Lastly, I threw in a Noise Texture as a Displacement to make the outside more "slimy" and bumpy looking as well. Also, pay attention to the Blend Mode highlighted on the right (switching away from *opaque* is necessary for transparency in EEVEE)

Comment: does it animate/fall if i put a softbody

Comment: Yeah of course - it's just a material. You can even further "animate" the bumpy outside to further effect if you want. You'll have to put a softbody on both cubes if you want them to fall together, though.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you putting so much effort into this!

Comment: Hey, no problem. If you need any more assistance with it, let me know,

Comment: Also, for the noise mixing node, what connects to which? Sorry, it's not very clear in the image.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I connected Fac from the Noise Texture (black and white output) to the top of the 2 color inputs of the MixRGB Node  (I'm mixing it with pure white). I find the raw value from the Noise Texture on it's own is often far too strong for the Displacement and looks unrealistic, so I "lighten" the whole image by mixing it with white.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120024/discussion-between-clobro-and-christopher-bennett).